# Difference between curr_node.ptr = &(next_node.ptr); and curr_node.ptr = &next_node

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, nodes

Example #1

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
    struct node *next;
    char *data;
};

struct node *reverse_list(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *curr, *prev, *next;
    curr = head;
    prev = NULL;
    next = curr->next;
    while(curr != NULL){
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    return prev;
}

int main(){
    struct node *reverse_list();
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding:

This code describe a link that every pointer points to next node's value(or the beginning of node), somehow it is a basic and simple structure.
But what if we want all the pointers point to next pointer and then reverse it? The process seems complex when we want to reverse it when all the pointer points to pointer.

That is,

curr_node.ptr = &(next_node.ptr);

NOT: curr_node.ptr = &next_node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curr_node.ptr = &(next_node.ptr)` gets the adresse of `ptr` in `next_node` wherease  `curr_node.ptr = &next_node` gets the adresse of `next_node`

If you're looking to reverse your linked list, just google what follows

> How to reverse a linked list in C

or

> rev_list.c
>    on github something like that.

Hope it helped.

Nicolas

Comment: I have tried it, but I realized that there is some details when I try to implement reverse function in a ptr 2 ptr linked list. Do you know some code example of that? thx

Comment: [my_rev_list.c](http://xf.iksaif.net/epitech/.rendu/piscine/Jour_11/my_rev_list.c)